# How do I reduce the height of a colored row in a table?

Tags: tables, height, rowcolor

I want to get this:
[image]

I wrote this, when I put `[-1.5ex]` after `\\`, I can get reduced row height but the color of the row is still normal row height. How can I make the color's height reduce? Any suggestion?

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}  \hline 

h & 0.00003 m&  0.00003 m\\\hline  
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.7,0.7,0.7} &  & \\[-1.5ex]\hline   
n & & \\\hline

\end{tabular}
```

The output: [image]

Comment: an example with the `cellspace` package is added below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With customization of rules defined by `hhline` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Summary}
    \centering
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\doublerulesep{0.5\baselineskip}  % <---
    \doublerulesepcolor{gray!30}                % <---
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c | L| L | }
    \hhline{|=|=|=|}
h   &   \qty{0,00003}{m}    &   \qty{0,00003}{m}    \\
    \hhline{|-|-|-|}
n   &                       &                       \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your codes and ıt worked. Thank you. Also we can do it without tabularx package and siunitx package.

Comment: @irem, of course it worked ;-). From image which you provide in question, I guess, that use of `tabularx` for table is good idea. Also numbers in table unknown to me, however use of `siunitx` enables their alignment at decimal points. If both is not needed in your final table, just dropout them from MWE. So, if answer fulfill your expectation (on the best way) you may consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font = footnotesize}
\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\newcolumntype{O}{>{\columncolor{mColor1}}}
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{0pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\caption{Summary}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| OD{2.2cm} | E{1.1cm} | S{E{3cm}} | E{3cm} | }
\hline
\rowcolor{mColor1}
 &  &   &   \tabularnewline
\hline
Author(s) & App. & Algorithm / Technique & Camera Type \\
\hline
Author(s) & App. & Algorithm / Technique & Camera Type \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; however, I want to make a half sized height line with colored.